# Como utilizar Curl com C#, aplicação windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer uma integração da minha aplicação desktop com uma ferramenta online (ScrumWise), porém eles utilizam Curl, não estou conseguindo consumir o rest.

```
curl https://api.scrumwise.com/service/api/v1/getData -k
  -u bob@example.com:69C0A6A9E957B6398BD8C62F3B67C95005CA...
  -d "projectIDs=729-11230-1,729-31745-129"
  -d "includeProperties=Project.backlogItems,BacklogItem.tasks"
```

estou com dificuldade nessa segunda linha aqui

```
-u bob@example.com:69C0A6A9E957B6398BD8C62F3B67C95005CA
```

como transcrever esse Curl em c#?

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa exatamente usar o cURL pra fazer isso. [Pode usar o RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) que é mais simples de usar:

```
var cookie = new CookieContainer();
var client = new RestClient("https://api.scrumwise.com/service/api/v1/getData")
{
    Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("bob@example.com", "69C0A6A9E957B6398BD8C62F3B67C95005CA"),
    CookieContainer = cookie
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "projectID=729-11230-1", ParameterType.RequestBody);
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "name=Example backlog item 1", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Não se esqueça de que você precisa gerar sua própria API Key. Esta que você está testando é só [o exemplo da documentação do ScrumWise](https://www.scrumwise.com/api.html#api-keys).